# Line Integral of ARBITRARY Vector Field $\vec F$ along a Circle

Tags: integration, proof-verification, vector-analysis, line-integrals

Currently I'm taking vector calculus lectures and recently, I was given some problems about line integrals of some vector field $\vec F$ along a region. And among which most of the regions stated is CIRCLE.

> Out of boredom, I attempt to generalize the result of line integrals of **arbitrary** vector field $\vec F:[u(x,y),v(x,y)]$ along a circle $C: x^2+y^2=r^2$, where $u$ and $v$ are scalar functions of $(x,y)$. (You may assume $u$ and $v$ are continuous and differentiable.)

**Here is my partial statement:**

Let $u(x,y)=\vec p(x)\cdot \vec q(y)=[p_1(x),p_2(x),\cdots,p_n(x)]\cdot[q_1(y),q_2(y),\cdots,q_n(y)]$, where $p_i(x)$ and $q_i(y)$ are scalar function of $x$ and $y$ respectively. Similarly, we denote $v(x,y)=\vec\alpha(x)\cdot\vec\beta(y)$.

Denote $\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}=\beta$.

\begin{align}
I&=\int_C\vec F(\vec r)d\vec r=\iint_R\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)dxdy
\\&=\iint_R\vec\alpha\prime(x)\cdot\vec\beta(y)-\vec p(x)\cdot \vec q\prime(y)dxdy
\\&=\int^r_{-r}[\vec\alpha\prime(x)\cdot\vec b(y)-\vec p(x)\cdot \vec q(y)]^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}dx
\\&=\int^r_{-r}\left(\vec\alpha\prime(x)\cdot\vec b(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})-\vec p(x)\cdot \vec q(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})\right)-\left(\vec\alpha\prime(x)\cdot\vec b(-\sqrt{r^2-x^2})-\vec p(x)\cdot \vec q(-\sqrt{r^2-x^2})\right)dx
\end{align}

Let

\begin{align}
J_1&=\int^r_{-r}\vec\alpha\prime(x)\cdot\vec b(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})dx\\&=\int^r_{-r}\vec b(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})d[\vec\alpha(x)]\\&=[\vec\alpha(x)\cdot\vec b(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})]^r_{-r}-\int^r_{-r}\vec\alpha(x)\cdot\vec\beta(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})d[\sqrt{r^2-x^2}]\\&=[\vec\alpha(r)-\vec\alpha(-r)]\cdot\vec b(0)-\int^r_{-r}v(x,\sqrt{r^2-x^2})d{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}
\end{align}

Similarly,

\begin{align}
J_2&=\int^r_{-r}\vec\alpha\prime(x)\cdot\vec b(-\sqrt{r^2-x^2})dx\\&=[\vec\alpha(r)-\vec\alpha(-r)]\cdot\vec b(0)+\int^r_{-r}v(x,-\sqrt{r^2-x^2})d{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}
\end{align}

Also

$$K_1=\int^r_{-r}\vec p(x)\cdot\vec q(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})dx=\int^r_{-r}u(x,\sqrt{r^2-x^2})dx$$
$$K_2=\int^r_{-r}\vec p(x)\cdot\vec q(-\sqrt{r^2-x^2})dx=\int^r_{-r}u(x,-\sqrt{r^2-x^2})dx$$

Bringing these integrals together and we get:

\begin{align}
I&=J_1-K_1-J_2+K_2\\&=\int^r_{-r}\left[u(x,-\sqrt{r^2-x^2})-u(x,\sqrt{r^2-x^2})\right]dx-\int^r_{-r}\left[v(x,\sqrt{r^2-x^2})+v(x,-\sqrt{r^2-x^2})\right]d{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}
\end{align}

This is what I've attempt. But can this expression be further simplified?

**Current aim:** Give a simpler form without integral signs. Smarter approaches are also welcomed.

Comment: Could somebody give me a piece of advice about it? Thank you.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. You said you want to generalize a result. What result are you referring to?

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim To express the line integral, if possible and necessary, in terms of functions $u,v$ and variables $x,y$ and constant $r$.

Comment: And more importantly, WITHOUT the integral sign.

Comment: Is part of your assumption that $u(x,y) = \vec p(x) \cdot \vec q(y)$? There's no reason for this to be true in general.

Comment: Yes I think I have just taken it for granted. And I see your point that there maybe some implicit functions involving multiplications and divisions of exponents. For instance, $u(x,y)=e^{xy}$ or $u(x,y)=e^{x/y}$ is hard or even impossible to express as an inner product. To be honest, I have no way to treat those function. Are there any means to express these functions or just take some assumptions?

Comment: thing would probably simplify if you do a variable conversion using \sin(\theta) = y/r and cos(\theta) = x/r

Comment: Could someone please help me? I only have 22 hours left to award the bounty...